# Are Mikasa and Levi the only two Ackermans alive?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Supposedly the Ackerman were a clan, so at some point there must have been many of them, and we knew Kenny who died during the series. But what about other members?

Are Mikasa and Levi the only two Ackermans alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quoted at [attackontitanwiki](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ackerman_clan)

> Only two known members are left.

It looks like only Mikasa and Levi are alive
Also, some other members are listed [here](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ackerman_clan#Members)